# Singleton Pattern Code implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, singleton

I have written this below code to connect to my database. Can you guys suggest me any better option than this as i am keenly interested into which way the performance of the goes better. Is the below code implementing the Singleton pattern or not?

```
    public static class DbConnect
    {

        public static DataTable SqlConnection(string query)
        {
            DataTable dt = null;

            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        {
                            dt = new DataTable();
                            cn.Open();
                            da.Fill(dt);
                        }
                    }
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Remove "if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)": it's better to get an exception that connection is broken than hide the problem and return an empty DataTable

Comment: You don't assign "query" ro SqlCommand.CommandText

Comment: Add Command Parameters support

Comment: yes thats the mistake, i was about to edit it. Any other stuff ?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko
Command Parameters support for StoredProcedures?

Comment: That's not a singleton. It's a static method.

Comment: @user3503349: You're implementing general purpose code, and since many stored procedures have parameters you'd rather add support for them.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a code review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that is, IMHO, expected:

1. Add parameters support
2. Do not hide errors: if connection is broken you should have an exception

So the code could look like that:

```
      // I've used KeyValuePair for parameters; probably a specialized class will be better 
      public static DataTable SqlConnection(string query, params KeyValuePair<String, Object>[] parameters) {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString)) {
          using (SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand()) {
            cmd.CommandText = query;

            // Parameters, if they're mentioned 
            if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, parameters))
              foreach (var prm in parameters)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(prm.Key, prm.Value);

            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)) {
              cn.Open();

              DataTable result = new DataTable();

              da.Fill(result);

              return result;
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

...

```
DataTable dt1 = SqlConnection("select 123");
DataTable dt2 = SqlConnection(
                   @"select * 
                      from MyTable 
                     where MyField = @MyParam", 
                   new KeyValuePair<String, Object>("@MyParam", 123));
```

P.S. The code is not a *Singleton* implementation, it's not even a *class*: just a *static method*.